# Error: RSA routines:decrypt:DATA_LEN_NOT_EQUAL_TO_MOD_LEN

Tags: android, rsa, android-keystore, android-security

I need to encrypt the ACCESS_TOKEN. While decrypting, getting error:
 ** error:0407806d:RSA routines:decrypt:DATA_LEN_NOT_EQUAL_TO_MOD_LEN**

> private String ACCESS_TOKEN = "bearer
>   nG25Uokr3eF0WAisEcoS4hb1isLwR2qbOGu3UnwARGfeBNlP7RToSf3DCmowl99-TX0nrwL1qElIRZALFNbBXQPL6weVhJk9LRjJAoD9oBlTPtfDNMAZXlLqBqWnYZoxNyfQoPUE_Y0iMBcj_j6RqOfJc4Npid7Wo1AoipXOPYt1JLMfdHN9TZvtn6SxNP9UFipDANkcnHsurDwjPV_X0PdzyqsgXuoIjfAQLd7IonVYGZYmB_SYO68q5CorhH7hA01iIm7TDeUrOAM1p2C9W84rV6nMzMZS-7LPoweMWPxaLHcj15ex3TR16PGNGwbfiRPMLxNjmpqQEi3Mfqax2mk9qHL6LNb-OQK_5y9Zo9w1nC55iQhM-PbF96kgYa5zM2o94yI1IhcWAs-fJEe5tPsT3Dj_QfLWeNVblzDysfNwNajCGnauuPLzG-5qrGgNRtw0Dou8eNhk1lplDXxqu-G9kRyK1KKnPtuyCawzEJ_-4aEHdeA3-QSEqWCphu6w";

Please refer the code:

```
import android.util.Base64;

import com.itc.classmate.application.MyApplication;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

/**
 * 
 */

public enum EncryptMoreThn256Byte {
    INSTANCE;
    private SecretKey secKey;
   // private String ACCESS_TOKEN = "bearer nG25Uokr3eF0WAisEcoS4hb1isLwR2qbOGu3UnwARGfeBNlP7RToSf3DCmowl99-TX0nrwL1qElIRZALFNbBXQPL6weVhJk9LRjJAoD9oBlTPtfDNMAZXlLqBqWnYZoxNyfQoPUE_Y0iMBcj_j6RqOfJc4Npid7Wo1AoipXOPYt1JLMfdHN9TZvtn6SxNP9UFipDANkcnHsurDwjPV_X0PdzyqsgXuoIjfAQLd7IonVYGZYmB_SYO68q5CorhH7hA01iIm7TDeUrOAM1p2C9W84rV6nMzMZS-7LPoweMWPxaLHcj15ex3TR16PGNGwbfiRPMLxNjmpqQEi3Mfqax2mk9qHL6LNb-OQK_5y9Zo9w1nC55iQhM-PbF96kgYa5zM2o94yI1IhcWAs-fJEe5tPsT3Dj_QfLWeNVblzDysfNwNajCGnauuPLzG-5qrGgNRtw0Dou8eNhk1lplDXxqu-G9kRyK1KKnPtuyCawzEJ_-4aEHdeA3-QSEqWCphu6w";
  //  private String initialText = "this is working";

    private EncryptMoreThn256Byte() {
        AppLog.log(EncryptMoreThn256Byte.class.getSimpleName(), "called constructor of EncryptMoreThn256Byte");
        KeyGenerator generator = null;
        try {
            generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            generator.init(128); // The AES key size in number of bits
            secKey = generator.generateKey();
            AppLog.log(EncryptMoreThn256Byte.class.getSimpleName(), "EncryptMoreThn256Byte: secKey+++ " + secKey.getEncoded());

//            SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
//            byte[] salt = new byte[(256/8)];
//            random.nextBytes(salt);
//            KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(initialText.toCharArray(), salt, 1000, 256);
//            SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
//            byte[] decrptedSecrateKey = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec).getEncoded();
//           // secKey = new SecretKeySpec(decrptedSecrateKey, "AES");
//            secKey = new SecretKeySpec(decrptedSecrateKey, 0, decrptedSecrateKey.length, "AES");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            AppLog.errLog(EncryptMoreThn256Byte.class.getSimpleName(), e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    public String encryptAccessTokenUsingAES(String plainText) {
        AppLog.log(EncryptMoreThn256Byte.class.getSimpleName(), "encryptAccessTokenUsingAES: plainText " + plainText);

        if (plainText != null || !plainText.isEmpty()) {
            String encrytedSecretKey = SharedPreferences.getInstance(MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext()).getEncrytedSecretKey();
            if (encrytedSecretKey != null) {
                AppLog.log(EncryptMoreThn256Byte.class.getSimpleName(), "encryptAccessTokenUsingAES: encrytedSecretKey >+++ " + encrytedSecretKey);
                byte[] decrptedSecrateKey = decryptSecretKeyUsingRSA(encrytedSecretKey);
                if (decrptedSecrateKey != null) {
                    secKey = new SecretKeySpec(decrptedSecrateKey, 0, decrptedSecrateKey.length, "AES");
                }
            } else {
                encryptSecretKeyUsingRSA(secKey);
            }

            String str = new String(encryptText(secKey, plainText));
            AppLog.log(EncryptMoreThn256Byte.class.getSimpleName(), "final encryptAccessTokenUsingAES is: " + str);
            return str;
        }

        AppLog.log(EncryptMoreThn256Byte.class.getSimpleName(), "encryptAccessTokenUsingAES: value " + null);
        return null;
    }


    public String decryptAccessTokenUsingAES(String encrptedAssessToken) {
        String encrpted_secretkey = SharedPreferences.getInstance(MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext()).getEncrytedSecretKey();
        AppLog.log(EncryptMoreThn256Byte.class.getSimpleName(), "decryptAccessTokenUsingAES encrpted_secretkey:: " + encrpted_secretkey);
        AppLog.log(EncryptMoreThn256Byte.class.getSimpleName(), "decryptAccessTokenUsingAES accesstoken:: " + encrptedAssessToken);
        if (encrpted_secretkey != null) {
            byte[] decrptedSecrateKey = decryptSecretKeyUsingRSA(encrpted_secretkey);
            if (decrptedSecrateKey != null) {
                SecretKey secKey = new SecretKeySpec(decrptedSecrateKey, 0, decrptedSecrateKey.length, "AES");
                AppLog.log(EncryptMoreThn256Byte.class.getSimpleName(), "decryptAccessTokenUsingAES secKey.getEncoded():: " + secKey.getEncoded());
                String str = decryptText(secKey, encrptedAssessToken);
                AppLog.log(EncryptMoreThn256Byte.class.getSimpleName(), "final decryptAccessTokenUsingAES is: " + str);
                return str;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private byte[] encryptSecretKeyUsingRSA(SecretKey secKey) {
        AppLog.log(EncryptMoreThn256Byte.class.getSimpleName(), "encryptSecretKeyUsingRSA SecretKey:: " + secKey);
        KeyPairGenerator kpg = null;
        byte[] encryptedSecrteKey = null;
        try {
            kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            kpg.initialize(2048);
            KeyPair keyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();
            PublicKey puKey = keyPair.getPublic();
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.PUBLIC_KEY, puKey);
            //AppLog.log(EncryptMoreThn256Byte.class.getSimpleName(), "encryptSecretKeyUsingRSA secKey.getEncoded():: " + secKey.getEncoded());
            //AppLog.log(EncryptMoreThn256Byte.class.getSimpleName(), "encryptSecretKeyUsingRSA secKey.getEncoded().length:: " + secKey.getEncoded().length);
            //byte[] encryptedSecrteKey = cipher.doFinal(secKey.getEncoded());
            //byte[] encryptedSecrteKey=cipher.doFinal(initialText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            encryptedSecrteKey = cipher.doFinal(secKey.getEncoded());
            // String str =  Base64.encodeToString(encryptedSecrteKey, Base64.DEFAULT);
            AppLog.log(EncryptMoreThn256Byte.class.getSimpleName(), "encryptSecretKeyUsingRSA encryptedSecrteKey[]:: " + encryptedSecrteKey.length);
            //AppLog.log(EncryptMoreThn256Byte.class.getSimpleName(), "encryptSecretKeyUsingRSA encrytionSecretKey:: " + str);
            //AppLog.log(EncryptMoreThn256Byte.class.getSimpleName(), "encryptSecretKeyUsingRSA encrytionSecretKey length:: " + str.length());
            SharedPreferences.getInstance(MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext()).setEncrytedSecretKey(encryptedSecrteKey.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            AppLog.errLog(EncryptMoreThn256Byte.class.getSimpleName(), "encryptSecretKeyUsingRSA::+" + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            return encryptedSecrteKey;
        }
    }


    private byte[] decryptSecretKeyUsingRSA(String encryptSecretKey) {
        KeyPairGenerator kpg = null;
        byte[] bytes = null;
        try {
            kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            kpg.initialize(2048);
            KeyPair keyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();
            PrivateKey prKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.PRIVATE_KEY, prKey);
            AppLog.log(EncryptMoreThn256Byte.class.getSimpleName(), "decryptSecretKeyUsingRSA encryptSecretKey.getBytes():: " + encryptSecretKey.getBytes());
            AppLog.log(EncryptMoreThn256Byte.class.getSimpleName(), "decryptSecretKeyUsingRSA encryptSecretKey.getBytes().length:: " + encryptSecretKey.getBytes().length);
           // bytes = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(encryptSecretKey, Base64.DEFAULT));
            bytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptSecretKey.getBytes());
            AppLog.log(EncryptMoreThn256Byte.class.getSimpleName(), "decryptSecretKeyUsingRSA cipher.doFinal(encryptSecretKey.getBytes():: " + bytes.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            AppLog.errLog(EncryptMoreThn256Byte.class.getSimpleName(), "decryptSecretKeyUsingRSA++++ " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return bytes;
    }


    private byte[] encryptText(SecretKey pSecKey, String plainText) {
        byte[] encryptAccessToken = null;
        try {
            AppLog.log(EncryptMoreThn256Byte.class.getSimpleName(), "encryptText::secKey: " + pSecKey.getEncoded());
            Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pSecKey);
            encryptAccessToken = aesCipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
            AppLog.log(EncryptMoreThn256Byte.class.getSimpleName(), "encryptText:::: " + encryptAccessToken.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            AppLog.errLog(EncryptMoreThn256Byte.class.getSimpleName(), "encryptTextUsingAES " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return encryptAccessToken;
    }

    /**
     * Convert bytes to AES SecertKey so we can decrypt access token
     *
     * @return
     */
    private String decryptText(SecretKey originalKey, String decryptedAccessToken) {
        byte[] bytePlainText = null;
        try {
            AppLog.log(EncryptMoreThn256Byte.class.getSimpleName(), "encryptText::originalKey: " + originalKey.getEncoded());
            //SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(decryptedKey, 0, decryptedKey.length, "AES");
            Cipher aesCipher = null;
            aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            aesCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, originalKey);
            bytePlainText = aesCipher.doFinal(decryptedAccessToken.getBytes());
            AppLog.log(EncryptMoreThn256Byte.class.getSimpleName(), "decryptText bytePlainText:: " + bytePlainText.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            AppLog.errLog(EncryptMoreThn256Byte.class.getSimpleName(), "encryptTextUsingAES " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return new String(bytePlainText);
    }


    private byte[] encrytAT(String plaintext, String password) throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] salt = new byte[(256 / 8)];
        random.nextBytes(salt);
        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 1000, 256);
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        byte[] keyBytes = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec).getEncoded();
        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        byte[] iv = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
        random.nextBytes(iv);
        IvParameterSpec ivParams = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivParams);
        return cipher.doFinal(plaintext.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    }

}
```

Also find the log for the same code:

```
03-28 11:47:59.536 12795-12795/? D/debug_log: EncryptMoreThn256Byte :encryptAccessTokenUsingAES: encrytedSecretKey >+++ [B@b56ec6b 03-2811:48:00.803 12795-12795/? D/debug_log: EncryptMoreThn256Byte :decryptSecretKeyUsingRSA encryptSecretKey.getBytes():: [B@43f8244
03-28 11:48:00.804 12795-12795/? D/debug_log: EncryptMoreThn256Byte :decryptSecretKeyUsingRSA encryptSecretKey.getBytes().length:: 10 03-2811:48:00.804 12795-12795/? E/error_log: Exception from:EncryptMoreThn256Byte : decryptSecretKeyUsingRSA++++error:0407806d:RSA routines:decrypt:DATA_LEN_NOT_EQUAL_TO_MOD_LEN
03-28 11:48:00.805 12795-12795/? D/debug_log: EncryptMoreThn256Byte :encryptText::secKey: [B@d535f2d 
03-28 11:48:00.808 12795-12795/? D/debug_log: EncryptMoreThn256Byte : encryptText:::: [B@d4d6c62 03-2811:48:00.808 12795-12795/? D/debug_log: EncryptMoreThn256Byte : finalencryptAccessTokenUsingAES is: (���(z��RW�D 
03-28 11:48:00.808 12795-12795/? D/debug_log: MyApplication : EncryptMoreThn256Byte +++str (���(z��RW�D 
03-28 11:48:00.808 12795-12795/? D/debug_log:EncryptMoreThn256Byte : decryptAccessTokenUsingAESencrpted_secretkey:: [B@b56ec6b 
03-28 11:48:00.808 12795-12795/? D/debug_log: EncryptMoreThn256Byte : decryptAccessTokenUsingAESaccesstoken:: (���(z��RW�D 
03-28 11:48:03.539 12795-12795/? D/debug_log: EncryptMoreThn256Byte : decryptSecretKeyUsingRSAencryptSecretKey.getBytes():: [B@6c931f3 
03-28 11:48:03.540 12795-12795/? D/debug_log: EncryptMoreThn256Byte :decryptSecretKeyUsingRSA encryptSecretKey.getBytes().length:: 10 03-2811:48:03.540 12795-12795/? E/error_log: Exception from:EncryptMoreThn256Byte : decryptSecretKeyUsingRSA++++error:0407806d:RSA routines:decrypt:DATA_LEN_NOT_EQUAL_TO_MOD_LEN
03-28 11:48:03.540 12795-12795/? D/debug_log: MyApplication :EncryptMoreThn256Byte +++ dep null
```

Comment: This seems just like a massive text dump, for people to help you it is better if you explain your code and tell what it should do. ( and maybe guess where the error might be). Also if you could slim it down to the relevant parts as described here https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve it would improve your question.

Comment: To understand the code, i have share whole class. Once you go through the code then only you come to know the fault. Well, while decrypt secret key by decryptSecretKeyUsingRSA(), i am getting error. Please check the log as well

Comment: to understand the code it is much better if you explain in detail what you are doing instead of us trying to figure it out on our selfes

Comment: You are generating a new RSA keypair every time on encrypt, which doesn't make sense. Then on decrypt you are also generating a new keypair every time, which makes even less sense if that's possible. `Cipher.PRIVATE_KEY` is not a legal argument as the mode to `Cipher.init()`. The `toString()` method on an array doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: @James: Thanks for your comment. I have posted new approach. Please review it.

Answer (score 0):

Plase, review this.

```
public class AESEncryptor {
    private static final String CIPHER_TYPE = "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding";//AES/GCM/NoPadding
    public final String ANDROID_KEY_STORE = "AndroidKeyStore";
    private static AESEncryptor instance;
    private String alias_ = "classmate123";
    private KeyStore keyStore;

    private AESEncryptor() {
    }

    public static AESEncryptor getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new AESEncryptor();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public KeyStore initAndroidKeyStore(Context pContext) {
        try {
            if (keyStore == null) {
                keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
                keyStore.load(null);
                createNewKeys(pContext);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            AppLog.errLog("AESEncrytion", "initAndroidKeyStore : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return keyStore;
    }

    public String encrypt(String key, String cleartext) throws Exception {
        //AppLog.log("AESEncrytion", "encrypt+++ " + cleartext);
        if (cleartext == null || cleartext.trim().length()==0||cleartext.isEmpty()) {
            return "";
        }
        return encryptString(alias_, cleartext);
    }


    public String decrypt(String key, String encryptedValue) throws Exception {
        //AppLog.log("AESEncrytion", "encryptedValue+++ " + encryptedValue);
        if (encryptedValue == null || encryptedValue.trim().length()==0||encryptedValue.isEmpty()) {
            return "";
        }
        return decryptString(alias_, encryptedValue);
    }


    public void createNewKeys(Context pContext) {
        String alias = alias_;
        try {
            // Create new key if needed
            if (!keyStore.containsAlias(alias)) {
                Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
                end.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
                AlgorithmParameterSpec spec = null;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(pContext)
                            // You'll use the alias later to retrieve the key.  It's a key for the key!
                            .setAlias(alias)
                            // The subject used for the self-signed certificate of the generated pair
                            .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=" + alias))
                            .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)
                            .setStartDate(start.getTime())
                            .setEndDate(end.getTime())
                            .build();
                }else {
                    // On Android M or above, use the KeyGenparameterSpec.Builder and specify permitted
                    // properties  and restrictions of the key.
                    spec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(alias, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN)
                            .setCertificateSubject(new X500Principal("CN=" + alias))
                            .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
                            .setSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
                            .setCertificateSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)
                            .setCertificateNotBefore(start.getTime())
                            .setCertificateNotAfter(end.getTime())
                            .build();
                }
                KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
                generator.initialize(spec);
                KeyPair keyPair = generator.generateKeyPair();
               // AppLog.log("AESEncrytion", "createNewKeys keyPair.getPrivate(): " + keyPair.getPrivate());
               // AppLog.log("AESEncrytion", "createNewKeys keyPair.getPublic(): " + keyPair.getPublic());
            } else {
                AppLog.log("AESEncrytion", "KeyStore already containsAlias alias: " + keyStore.containsAlias(alias));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            AppLog.errLog("AESEncrytion", "createNewKeys: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        //refreshKeys();
    }


    public String encryptString(String alias, String initialText) {
        try {
            //AppLog.log("AESEncrytion", "initialText+++ " + initialText);
            KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(alias, null);
            PublicKey publicKey = privateKeyEntry.getCertificate().getPublicKey();
            //AppLog.log("AESEncrytion", "encryptString keyPair.getPublic(): " + publicKey.getEncoded());
            // RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) privateKeyEntry.getCertificate().getPublicKey();

            Cipher input = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_TYPE);
            input.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
            byte[] encrypted=input.doFinal(initialText.getBytes("UTF-8"));

//            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
//            CipherOutputStream cipherOutputStream = new CipherOutputStream(outputStream, input);
//            cipherOutputStream.write(initialText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
//            cipherOutputStream.close();
//            byte[] vals = outputStream.toByteArray();
//            AppLog.log("AESEncrytion", "decryptString+++ " + Base64.encodeToString(vals, Base64.DEFAULT));

            return Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, Base64.DEFAULT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            AppLog.errLog("AESEncrytion", "encryptString " + e.getMessage() + " occured");
        }
        return "";
    }


    public String decryptString(String alias, String cipherText) {
        try {
            //AppLog.log("AESEncrytion", "cipherText : " + cipherText);
            KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(alias, null);
            // RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) privateKeyEntry.getPrivateKey();
            PrivateKey privateKey = privateKeyEntry.getPrivateKey();
            //AppLog.log("AESEncrytion", "decryptString keyPair.getPrivate(): " + privateKey.getEncoded());

            Cipher output = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_TYPE);
            output.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
            byte[] decrypted=output.doFinal(Base64.decode(cipherText, Base64.DEFAULT));

//            CipherInputStream cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(
//                    new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(cipherText, Base64.DEFAULT)), output);
//            ArrayList<Byte> values = new ArrayList<>();
//            int nextByte;
//            while ((nextByte = cipherInputStream.read()) != -1) {
//                values.add((byte) nextByte);
//            }
//            byte[] bytes = new byte[values.size()];
//            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
//                bytes[i] = values.get(i).byteValue();
//            }
            String finalText = new String(decrypted, 0, decrypted.length, "UTF-8");
           // AppLog.log("AESEncrytion", "decryptString : " + finalText);
            return finalText;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            AppLog.errLog("AESEncrytion", "decryptString:: " + e.getMessage() + " occured");
        }
        return "";
    }

    public boolean isKeysAvail() throws KeyStoreException {
        return keyStore.containsAlias(alias_);
    }

    public void deleteKey() throws KeyStoreException {
        keyStore.deleteEntry(alias_);
    }


}
```

It has solved my problem. I have changed my approach to encrypt and decrypt.

Comment: This bears almost no relation to your original question.

Comment: I changed the approach as I said.